# substract specific boxes as from lines in csv files

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have this file :

```
Month,CPU,RAM
July 2018,19%,46%
August 2018,20%,45%
September 2018,20%,41%
October 2018,21%,39%
November 2018,21%,39%
December 2018,21%,41%
January 2019,25%,46%
February 2019,27%,50%
```

I need to calculate the difference between the values in the second column but two by two:

For exemple :

```
July  -> August
CPU : +1% ( because 20-19)

August -> September 
CPU : +0% ( because 20-20)

September -> October
CPU : +1% ( because 21-20)
```

I try this with July and August :

```
cat myfile.txt | egrep "July|August" | awk -F',' '{diff-=$2} END {print diff}'
```

But the result is :

```
39
```

And the problem is that I have to specify July and August, which is not efficient because I have to do this for the other months too.

Is there a way to calculate the difference between these values? I just need to know the difference between the values ( value 2 - value 1, value 3 - value 2 - value 2 - value 4 - value 3 etc...), not necessarily to have the same presentation as in my example.

Please, can you show me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ ,%]' '
  NR>3{print ""}
  NR>2{printf "%s -> %s\nCPU : %+d%% (because %d-%d)\n",month,$1,$3-usage,$3,usage}
  NR>1{month=$1;usage=$3}
' file
July -> August
CPU : +1% (because 20-19)

August -> September
CPU : +0% (because 20-20)

September -> October
CPU : +1% (because 21-20)

October -> November
CPU : +0% (because 21-21)

November -> December
CPU : +0% (because 21-21)

December -> January
CPU : +4% (because 25-21)

January -> February
CPU : +2% (because 27-25)
```

---

it's really easy to adjust the output format even for beginners. for example, if you want a more compact output:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,%]' 'NR>2{printf "%-9s -> %-9s : %+3d%%\n",month,$1,$3-usage} NR>1{month=$1;usage=$3}' file
July      -> August    :  +1%
August    -> September :  +0%
September -> October   :  +1%
October   -> November  :  +0%
November  -> December  :  +0%
December  -> January   :  +4%
January   -> February  :  +2%
```

Comment: It works well ! Thanks !  Can you explain quickly the 4 lines of your script ?

Comment: @Makmy you don't need an explanation for this, read an awk manual and you'll get it in at most 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '
    NR>2{ printf "%s -> %s\nCPU : %+d%% ( because %d-%d)\n\n", p[1], $1, $3-p[3], $3, p[3] }
    { split($0,p) }
' file
July -> August
CPU : +1% ( because 20-19)

August -> September
CPU : +0% ( because 20-20)

September -> October
CPU : +1% ( because 21-20)

October -> November
CPU : +0% ( because 21-21)

November -> December
CPU : +0% ( because 21-21)

December -> January
CPU : +4% ( because 25-21)

January -> February
CPU : +2% ( because 27-25)
```

Comment: this prints an extra empty line at the end right? I mean you didn't do that accidentally

Comment: @oguzismail Right - it prints a blank line after every multi-line output record just like if you were doing multi-line record operations in paragraph mode with `RS=""; ORS="\n\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` :

```
awk -F'[ ,%]' '
               FNR>2{print m " -> " $1;printf "CPU : %+d%%%s",$3-u,ORS}
               {m=$1;u=$3}
              ' file
```

**Output**

```
July -> August
CPU : +1%
August -> September
CPU : +0%
September -> October
CPU : +1%
October -> November
CPU : +0%
November -> December
CPU : +0%
December -> January
CPU : +4%
January -> February
CPU : +2%
```

Comment: Thank you !
And if I want to delete the first line with " Month, CPU, RAM " and start from July ?
How to do this ?

Comment: @Makmy I am sorry, I didn't get you. This script automatically neglects the first line as it is irrelevant to our computation.